# Custom message on page refresh

Tags: javascript, html

Custom text is currently **not supported** in the `beforeunload` event prompt ([here the docu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload#Browser_compatibility)). Is there any alternative to show a custom message to the user before refreshing the page?

This is my code, which shows the standard prompt, but it is not possible to do a custom message.

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
    var confirmationMessage = "If you refresh your page you will need to use the link provided by the coordinator to access again. Do you want to continue?";
    e.returnValue = confirmationMessage;
    return confirmationMessage;
});
```

Comment: Can you give an example of this *"custom message"* and include your attempt to execute/display it before *"refreshing"*? Thank you.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the problem  with sample code

Comment: Done! You have the code in the problem description

Comment: Cant you just pop a confirm box https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm in the event handler?  And then return null, and cancel event (prevent default). No matter what you do, you are going to be in the hands of browser implementation, I think.

Comment: No, `confirm` and `alert` within the event handler are blocked by the browser, printing a message like this:
`Blocked confirm('If you refresh your page you will need to use the link sent by the coordinator to access again. Do you want to continue?') during beforeunload.`

Comment: Which browser are you checking? Check your code in IE, chrome will not support custom message.

Comment: That's why I'm looking for an alternative... Something that works in all browsers

Comment: A possible solution is to compare the current url with the destination url if you wont consider security and privacy concerns.

Comment: @PrathapG — How does comparing two URLs allow the OP to display a message?